# Found a family members possible arrest record, looking for a translation to English

Tags: translation

Apologies if this isn't the correct place to post this. Please feel free to guide me somewhere else. Or if I should format this question better.

My mostly non-Italian speaking family found an old family members possible arrest record.

Can anyone translate this image to English? We're mostly looking for what the arrest was for and any other important information.

I know the cursive may be very hard to read...

[image]

Comment: https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/are-questions-about-translation-requests-on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was not an arrest record but a request for disclosure of your relative’s criminal record, where results that he had nothing preceding the date of request.

Also nowadays when you’re applying for a job you’re requested to provide, along with many other certifications, this document which states your criminal record.

The document can be roughly translated like this:

> Criminal record
>
> Public Prosecution Service attached to the Cosenza District Court
>
> At the name of (your relative’s name) Di fu (your relative father’s
>   name) di fu (your relative mother’s name) birth on 19/11/1917 in
>   Cosenza following the request issued by (unreadable) to be used for every 
>   appropriate purpose we certify that his criminal record contains 
>   
> **NOTHING** 
> September 17, 1948

Comment: Abarisone, dovresti sapere che le richieste di traduzione sono off-topic...

Comment: Avresti anche ragione. Eh, su @DaG, un po' di spirito natalizio!

Comment: Allora se chiedo qui la ricetta della crema al mascarpone da mettere sul panettone mi rispondi? :)

Comment: Magari in privato sulla chat, che sono geloso delle mie ricette!! :-))